# Avoid double typing class names in python

Tags: python

This seems like a silly question but I haven't been able to come across the answer anywhere. Within my various packages I have a set of modules, usually each containing one class. When I want to create an instance of a class I have to refer to it twice:

Example:
package/obj.py:

```
class obj(object):
    pass
```

file.py:

```
import package.obj
my_obj = package.obj.obj()
```

Is there a way to reorganize my code such that I don't have to type the name twice? Ideally I'd like to just have to type package.obj().

Comment: In `__init__.py`, `from obj import obj`, then in `file.py`, you can use `from package import obj; my_obj = obj()`

Comment: Because sfpiano put actual code snippets in to show what (s)he was talking about.

Comment: In this situation, you should always ask yourself why you are only putting one class in each module.

Comment: The reason I'm mainly having one class per file has to do with the length of each class (LOC).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Python is not Java.  Feel free to put many classes into one file and then name the file according to the category:

```
import mypackage.image

this_image = image.png(...)
that_image = image.jpeg(....)
```

If your classes are so large you want them in separate files to ease the maintenance burden, that's fine, but you should not then inflict extra pain on your users (or yourself, if you use your own package ;).  Gather your public classes in the package's `__init__` file (or a category file, such as `image`) to present a fairly flat namespace:

mypackage's `__init__.py` (or `image.py`):

```
from _jpeg import jpeg
from _png import png
```

mypackage's `_jpeg.py`:

```
class jpeg(...):
    ...
```

mypackage's `_png.py`:

```
class png(...):
    ...
```

user code:

```
# if gathered in __init__
import mypackage
this_image = mypackage.png(...)
that_image = mypackage.jpeg(...)
```

or:

```
# if gathered in image.py
from mypackage import image
this_image = image.png(...)
that_image = image.jpeg(....)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `from ... import ...` statement:

```
from package.obj import obj
my_obj = obj()
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your classes and modules meaningful names. That's the way. Name your module 'classes' and  name your class 'MyClass'.

```
from package.classes import MyClass

myobj = MyClass()
```