# One class per file causes double names in python

Tags: python

So I have a small project of my own in Python which I want to regularly use. It is, at the moment, composed of two classes, let's call them class `Aclass` and `Bclass`.

The amount of code in both classes combined is large. So large that I do not want to *have* to have them in one file, so I create one file for each. I put the first into the file `aclass.py`, the second into `bclass.py` so my structure now looks something like this:

```
my_project/
  aclass.py
  bclass.py
  __init__.py
```

What I want is to be able to call my project from python and have the classes ready, like so:

```
import my_project
a_instance = my_project.Aclass()
b_instance = my_project.Bclass()
```

At the moment, what I have to do is

```
import my_project
a_instance = my_project.aclass.Aclass()
```

Which, if you ask me, is redundant. In the question:

[Avoid double typing class names in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19010969/avoid-double-typing-class-names-in-python)

I saw an advice to put

```
from aclass import Aclass
from bclass import Bclass
```

into the `__init__.py` file, but this causes confusion, because if I do that, I can create an instance of my class either by writing

```
import my_project
a_instance = my_project.Aclass()
```

or by writing

```
import my_project
a_instance = my_project.aclass.Aclass()
```

I find this solution ugly, because not only does it "double" the functions (creating both `aclass.Aclass()` and `Aclass()`, but it also means that any instance of the class Aclass will now be, in Python's eyes,

```
<class my_project.aclass.Aclass at ******************>
```

instead of

```
<class my_project.Aclass at ******************>
```

### which it is in the natural project structure.

Thus, my question is this:

Is there a solution to my problem in which `Aclass` will be located directly inside the `my_project` package without writing the class into the `__init__` file?

Comment: No, there isn't. The alternative is to just combine the classes in one module. Plenty of projects do this, *and* import objects into an `__init__` to provide a simple, clear API to the developer using the package.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I understand that many projects do this, I was just hoping it isn't the only way to do it and that there exists a more OO-friendly way of doing it. Basically, as it stands now, I can either have classes or a good file structure...

Comment: I don't see your issue here, really. And just because it is possible to import the object from a deeper module, doesn't mean you cannot document the canonical location being the package.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's not the `__repr__` that bothers me, it's the fact that that's the way python sees the structure: there is a class in a file in the package. I see the structure as: there is a class in the package.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The issue is that I cannot get the effect of having a class directly in the `__init__.py` file without actually putting it there. That clunks up the `__init__.py` file, and leaves my in a 'one-file-per-package' state which is a mess.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I guess that answer will have to do, yes. I don't like it, but hey, if it's the best you got, I'll take it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Good point. Still don't like it, though. Feels kind of dirty. But that's a phylosophical debate for another day. I would love to accept your answer, if it was posted as such...

Comment: Isn't that pretty much the purpose of the `__init__.py` file besides its existence marking a folder as python package?

Comment: @5xum It may make it feel less dirty if you remember that *classes are just objects*. It doesn't make much sense to expect the existence of a "canonical location" in the code to something that is *instantiated at runtime*.

Comment: @goncalopp That... helps, strangely. Thank you.

Comment: The class is `<class my_project.aclass.Aclass at ******************>` but you've created an alias at `my_project.AClass`. Is that so much different than C's `using namespace xxx` or XMLs `xmlns:`? They are both there to reduce typing for those that don't think the extra qualifications should be sprinkled throughout their code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**; you only have two choices, either:

1. Put everything in one file, and have only a single route to each object at the cost of an unwieldy codebase; or
2. Have multiple files and use the `__init__.py` to define what's available at the top level of your library, accepting that this will mean multiple routes to an object.

For any project beyond a handful of classes and functions, the latter is clearly preferable; it is widely used in the standard library and beyond. For example, with [the `json` library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html), where the [`__init__.py`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0a32764004ab/Lib/json/__init__.py) includes `from .decoder import JSONDecoder`:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.JSONDecoder
<class 'json.decoder.JSONDecoder'>
>>> json.JSONDecoder is json.decoder.JSONDecoder
True
```

In the overwhelming majority of cases, any user of your code will use the shorter name rather than the longer name but, as they point to the same object, it doesn't *really* matter if they mix and match, and you will rarely have any occasion to see what *"Python thinks"* the fully-qualifed class name is.

Comment: What does the "." do prior to name in the json `__init__.py` file? The containing files (e.g., decoder.py) do not seem to be named with a ".".

Comment: @slaughter98 that means *"look for a module named decoder in the current directory"*.